# How to stop IntelliJ IDEA from expanding the "External Libraries" with "Autoscroll from Source" enabled?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, view, project

I'm using IntelliJ with Java and the "Always Select Opened File" function enabled.

I like when the IDE jumps to the class in the package list, but it will also expand the "External Libraries" making the whole "Project" view pretty messy.

Is there a way to stop IntelliJ from expanding External Libraries?

Comment: I'd like to know other side of this. How to enable autoscroll to external libraries? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153641/how-to-enable-scroll-from-source-to-external-libraries-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Different flavor of the same IDE: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35189/.py-files-are-opened-under-External-Libraries-in-the-Project-view-instead-of-directly-in-Project

Answer (score 5):

Same problem. Especially when you have a lot `maven artifacts` of your own.

Did not find any appropriate plugin.

Workaround: Switch in "`Project Tool Window`" from "`Project View`" to "`Packages`" and disable "`Show Library Contents`" `(can be found where is "Autoscroll from Source" option located )`

Comment: Unfortunately, "Packages" view is very inconvenient for projects with multiple modules.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to "Project Files" from "Project" helped me in PyCharm.
Probably will work the same way in IntelliJ IDEA:
[image]