# How to enable scroll from source to external libraries in intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'd like to see the location of a decompiled class in the external libraries tree.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to get to the package of the shown decompiled class:

`ctrl+click` on the package in the code (top most command in the java file).

Comment: Normally the _Scroll from source_ icon from Project Structure view should work but after updating IDEA it suddenly stopped. Your suggestion is working totally fine :)